# Spring Boot - "Path index.html does not start with a "/" character"

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am learning spring-boot and AngularJS, using Eclipse as an IDE, and Tomcat 8.0.30 (64 bits) as the container, running inside Eclipse. It is a Maven project.

Although the application is very basic and silly, I am getting an error when accessing the application via browser. The problem is, if I don't enter the URL with a slash (/) in the end, I got an error. The server logs throws this:

Url http://localhost:8080/app

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path index.html does not start with a "/" character
```

However, if I enter the url like http://localhost:8080/app/ then the application runs fine.

As you may know, spring-boot applications don't rely on *web.xml*. In fact, spring-boot loads *index.html* as the welcome page, or it is supposed to.

I ran the application outside Eclipse, by deploying to a Tomcat container. I got a 404 without the slash, and with the slash, it works fine. By running in self-contained mode (embeeded Tomcat) it works just fine.

**Why the application does not redirect to index.html without the slash in the end?**

You can find the entire application here (I am tagged it):

https://github.com/ajkret/spring-boot-sample/tree/slash-problem

Here is my Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "br.com.cinq.greet" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)).run(args);
    }
}
```

Here my ResourceConfig, for Jersey.

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class Config extends ResourceConfig {

    public Config() {
        register(GreetResource.class);
    }
}
```

Here is the GreetResource, a typical Jersey Resource:

```
@Path("/greet")
public class GreetResource {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetResource.class);

    // For now, store the information on a bean, in memory
    @Autowired
    Greet greet;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response greet() {
        logger.debug("Received GET requisition");
        return Response.ok().entity(greet).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response greet(Greet greet) {
        try {
            this.greet.setMessage(greet.getMessage());
            logger.info("Greeting message updated {}",this.greet.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("An exception occurred during Greet message update", e);
            return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("exception").build();
        }

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

That is it, all Java classes that may interfere with the process are here.

Here are the dependencies for the POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

---

***UPDATE***

I've installed Tomcat 8.0.24, and the problem was solved, apparently.

Are there new rules, RFCs, something new I don't know about the slash?